# database and java in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

this is my table for employee registration.while running my code, error will be displays

please give the reason and solutions

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEE_REGISTRATION" 
   (    "SALUTATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "MIDDLENAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "MARITALSTATUS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "DATEOFBIRTH" DATE, 
    "MOB-STD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "MOBILENUMBER" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "STD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "TELEPHONENUMBER" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "LANGUAGE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "MOTHERSMAIDEN" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CURRENTADDRESS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "PERMANENTADDRESS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "OCCUPATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "EDUCATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "EMPID" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "COMPANYNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "ANNUALINCOME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "SOURCEOFFUNDS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "DRIVINGLISCENCE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "PAYROLL" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "PANCARD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "AADHARNUMBER" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "EMPSTATUS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "HIREDDATE" DATE
   )
```

**here is my code with swing components in netbeans:**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (evt.getSource() == jButton1)
     {
        int x = 0;

        String s1 = jTextField2.getText();//firstname
        String s2 = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();//salutation
        String s3 = jTextField3.getText();//middlename
        String s4 = jTextField4.getText();//last name
        String s5 = jTextField5.getText();//username
        char[] s6 = jPasswordField1.getPassword();//password
        char[] s7 = jPasswordField2.getPassword(); //confirm password
        String s8 = new String(s6);
        String s9 = new String(s7);
        String s10= jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString();//marital status

        //SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
        //dateChooserCombo1.setDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
        String s11=dateChooserCombo1.getDateFormat().toString();

        String s12= jTextField6.getText();//+91
        String s13= jTextField7.getText();//Mobile
        String s14= jTextField8.getText();//std
        String s15= jTextField9.getText();//telephone
        String s16= jTextField10.getText();//email
        String s17= jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString();//prefered language
        String s18= jTextField13.getText();//mother's maiden name
        String s19= jTextArea1.getText();//current address
        //String s20= jCheckBox1.getSelectedIcon().toString();//same address
        String s21=jTextArea2.getText();//permanent address
        String s22= jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString();//state
        String s23= jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().toString();//city
        String s24= jComboBox7.getSelectedItem().toString();//occupation
        String s25= jComboBox8.getSelectedItem().toString();//education
        String s26= jTextField1.getText();//emp id
        String s27= jTextField14.getText();//company name
        String s28= jComboBox9.getSelectedItem().toString();//annual income
        String s29= jComboBox10.getSelectedItem().toString();//source of funds
        String s30= jTextField11.getText();//liscence number
        String s31= jComboBox11.getSelectedItem().toString();//payroll mode
        String s32= jTextField15.getText();//PAN number
        String s33= jTextField16.getText();//aadhar number
        String s34= jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();//Status
        String s35= jTextField17.getText();//hired date



        if (s8.equals(s9))
       {
            try
           {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "oracle");
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into employee_registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, s2);//salutation
                ps.setString(2, s1);//fname
                ps.setString(3, s3);//midname
                ps.setString(4, s4);//lastname
                ps.setString(5, s5);//username
                ps.setString(6, s8);//password
                ps.setString(7, s10);//marital status
                ps.setString(8, s11);//date of birth
                ps.setString(9, s12);//+91
                ps.setString(10, s13);//mobile
                ps.setString(11, s14);//std
                ps.setString(12, s15);//telephone
                ps.setString(13, s16);//email
                ps.setString(14, s17);//lang
                ps.setString(15, s18);//mothers maiden
                ps.setString(16, s19);//current address
                ps.setString(17, s21);//permanent address
                ps.setString(18, s22);//state
                ps.setString(19, s23);//city
                ps.setString(20, s24);//occupation
                ps.setString(21, s25);//education
                ps.setString(22, s26);//empid
                ps.setString(23, s27);//company
                ps.setString(24, s28);//income
                ps.setString(25, s29);//source of funds
                ps.setString(26, s30);//driving liscence
                ps.setString(27, s31);//payroll
                ps.setString(28, s32);//pan
                ps.setString(29, s33);//aadhar
                ps.setString(30, s34);//emp status
                ps.setString(31, s35);//hired date


                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                x++;
                if (x > 0) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jButton1, "Data Saved Successfully");
                }
            }
      catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

            if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jCheckBox1,"JCheckBox is selected");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jCheckBox1,"JCheckBox is NOT selected");

            }
        }
      else
       {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jButton1, "Password Does Not Match");
        } 
    } 
      else
   {
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jPasswordField1.setText("");
        jPasswordField2.setText("");
        jTextField3.setText("");
        jTextField4.setText("");
        jTextField5.setText("");
        jTextField6.setText("");
        jTextField7.setText("");
        jTextField8.setText("");
        jTextField9.setText("");
        jTextField10.setText("");
        jTextField11.setText("");
        //jTextField12.setText("");
        jTextField13.setText("");
        jTextField14.setText("");
        jTextField15.setText("");
        jTextField16.setText("");
        jTextField17.setText("");
    }

}
```

**Error displaying while running**

java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Answer (score 2):

> a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
ps.setString(...);
```

Maybe instead of using setString() everywhere you should try using `setInt(...)` or `setDate(...)` based on the appropriate data type of the column?

So maybe you need to convert the text from the text fields to an appropriate data type?